# How to get Rails form_for to point towards different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes, erb

I have a form for creating new comments. This code exists in a page that is under a different controller (let's say it's `app/views/posts/show.html.erb`).

```html
<%= form_for Comment.new do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :content %>
  <%= f.text_field :content %><br/>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The form works if I have `Comment.new` like above, but I want to use an instance variable like `form_for @comment`, similar to the first code snippet in this link: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html

In order to do so, I thought I need to define a `new` function like this and assign an empty comment. I tried putting this code in both the `posts_controller` and `comments_controller`.

```rb
def new
  @comment = Comment.new
end
```

But when I replace `Comment.new` with `@comment,` I get this error: `ActionView::Template::Error (First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty):`
This leads me to believe that neither of the `new` methods are being called. What am I doing wrong here?

My `routes.rb` looks like this:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'posts#show'
  resources :messages
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using show page (`app/views/posts/show.html.erb`) to display form
add this line in the show action of posts controller

```
# posts_controller
def show
  @comment = Comment.new
end
```

and if you also want to submit your form other than the comment's create action mention the `url` in `form_for` tag

```
<%= form_for @comment, url: posts_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :content %>
  <%= f.text_field :content %><br/>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Now that you say it, it makes so much sense! Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help!!